# How to open communication PYTHON socket with a SERVER SOCKET on AWS EC2 to a CLIENT SOCKET on my local pc?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, sockets, amazon-ec2, hosting

Sorry my english is not good

I want to established connexion from my client socket on my local pc to a host server socket on AWS EC2 instance.

I'm trying to follow suggestions from here and code from here.

The issue I'm facing is that I do not know how to open a socket and listen to incoming traffic on EC2. My EC2 is a UBUNTU free tier instance. No matter what I try I can't get it to work.

Someone said here that you have to put the private address of the EC2 on the client side and the public address on the server side. But I don't know specifically what address it is especially since I'm using an ubuntu engine

And how to run socket server program 24/7 ?

How can i check the good security group for allow the connection?????????

I would appreciate if somebody showed me how to do this properly.

Please please

That is my server socket (On my AWS EC2)

I first placed the public ip address of my ec2 instance as the hostname of my socket server and also as the hostname of my socket client.
Please I would like to know if it is possible that the communication is blocked by a firewall? or is it the customer who does not reach the right target?

How can i check the good security group for allow the connection?????????

When running the server fails to start.
But when I use the private address of the EC2 instance it runs fine.

But at the client level I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Administrateur/PycharmProjects/flask_3template/chatroomClient3333.py", line 12, in <module>
    client.connect((host, port))
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] Une tentative de connexion a échoué car le parti connecté n’a pas répondu convenablement au-delà d’une certaine durée ou une connexion établie a échoué car l’hôte de connexion n’a pas répondu

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Did you try running your server locally first?

Comment: Yes the server work perfectly on local

Comment: Just a heads up: There is no free tier instance on AWS. You are allowed to use certain types for a certain duration for free but the moment you surpass the duration , cost will be created.

Comment: I have solved the issue by configure the security group of my instance ec2 for allow my local ip pc in the inbound rules